# Create Custom Ribbon Tab with New Document Flyout

Tags: content-type, ribbon

My boss wants me to assume that the clients are complete idiots and that the standard document tab with all the options is too scary even with all the options grayed out. He wants me to create a custom ribbon tab with two buttons. One would work just like the new document button but present the list of only document content types, the other would present the list of only folder content types. Obviously this can't be hard coded since the list of available content types changes from library to library.

I am fairly comfortable with event receivers and the OM but this task requires me to use JavaScript and i have no idea where to begin. So far I have a custom tab with two flyouts with static code and JavaScript that creates a pop up and says hi for all menu options.

Can anyone either tell me how to do this or link an article that describes something similar? Also if there is someplace where I can get the code for the New Document button and its accompanying JavaScript, I can probably figure it out from there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually like this idea. Another "Option" for the modal dialog (assuming that you are going with the modal dialog) would be "Which library would you like to upload this to?" This sounds like a fun project. Here is a couple links from microsoft to get your started.

[Customizing and Extending the SharePoint 2010 Server Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[A great ribbon customization article called, "Customizing the Ribbon" by Chris O'Brien](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html)